# Is there a way to copy a directory full of files and change their file extentions in a Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

## Problem

I want to copy all the files in a directory over to my container, changing the extension.

## Setup

Lets say I want my local directory `src/*` copied into the container at `/work/`

`src/` contains a bunch of files with extensions like `.txt`.

I want to `COPY` them over and change their extensions to `.textfile`.

Currently I am doing

```
COPY src/file1.txt /work/file1.textfile
COPY src/file2.txt /work/file2.textfile
COPY src/file3.txt /work/file3.textfile
...
```

This works file but create a bunch of layers in my image and I'd like to just have it done in one step.

## What I've tried

```
COPY src/*.text /work/*.textfile
```

This doesn't work.

## Work around

I installed `util-linux` and used the `rename` command like so:

```
COPY src/*.txt /work/
RUN rename '.txt' '.textfile' /work
```

But this is undesirable as the command comes as a package.

## Question

Is there a way to do this simply as a dockerfile command?

Comment: Try this:
Using CMD (exec form)
cmd copy file newloc

Comment: Citation - https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-cmd-command-in-docker

Comment: CMD COPY src/file1.txt /work/file1.text 
Try something like that .. not sure of your directory structure but MAYBE its ../work but give this a try and let us know if you have any luck.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding but isn't the CMD keyword used to specify the command that should run on container execution?
My problem is with the extensions of the files. I can do `COPY src/ /work` but then the extensions stay the same

Comment: Oh I see you are getting the direct director copy command to work, but it is not allowing you to rename the extensions ?    Its probably a directory formatting issue .. in DOS if you wanted to work from a root but also use another directory structure it would be more like this:

copy src/file.txt ../work/file1.text 

I don't know what your folder structure looks like but if you can show us that I can help get a more direct answer if this one doesn't help.

Comment: Can you show us your directory structure?

Comment: Clarified some things.
There are no issues with actually coping the files over.
The problem I am having is specifically related to the naming of the files.
I basically want to work with a certain type of extension in the source of my program but then change that extension in the container.
Looking at the `COPY` Dockerfile command it FELLS like I am just missing something obvious to do that in one step.